# Enable volume management in Thunar on a Guix System

Tags: guix, guixsd, scheme

On my system I have installed both `thunar` and `thunar-volman`:

```
$ guix package --list-installed | grep thunar
thunar-volman   0.9.5   out /gnu/store/yp5xyyvvc59ivghszgyfwy3izd8jvqz0-thunar-volman-0.9.5
thunar  1.8.16  out /gnu/store/4hy62y05g34hwrhlyk8vjhka47d5bmhq-thunar-1.8.16
```

But when volume management is disabled the advanced settings looks like follows:

[image: Missing gvfs dependency.]

But `gvfs` is installed, at least according to the package manager.

```
$ guix package --list-installed | grep gvfs
gvfs    1.40.1  out /gnu/store/qg1827ai9j5raypmdajw3k7cibsqdykz-gvfs-1.40.1
```

Is this a packaging issue or, as I think I've read before, is it that Guix hasn't solved how to deal with dynamic dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the service available for all users through the system configuration file.

Edit your `/etc/config.scm` as follows:

```
  (packages
(append
  (list (specification->package "nss-certs")
        (specification->package "gvfs"))
  %base-packages))
```

Then run:

```
sudo guix system reconfigure /etc/config.scm
sudo reboot
```

[10.14 Invoking guix system](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-system.html)

[10.1 Using the Configuration System](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Using-the-Configuration-System.html)

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue, but I find it strange that a reboot was needed. In code no service is added, only a package; even though you write about a service. Could it be that there are some environment variables set/available during login when the package is installed at the system level?